# Horizontal image rotation

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I have animation with which the picture rotates clockwise (vertical space). In turn, I need to make the pictures rotated in the horizontal space.

my example of vertical rotation, help please with horizontal rotation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Resource->Create anim folder->xml file with any name

```
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <scale
            android:fromXScale=".3"
            android:toXScale="1.0"
            android:fromYScale="0.3"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="800" />

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="180"

            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="800" />

</set>
```

Now you can use this animation anywhere and no of times as well

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.[yourlayout]);

    findViewById(R.id.outer).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.your_file_nmae));

}
```